# Why views not destroying completely in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

When go to some View, go back, and then go again to this view, variables have data, so my view is not completely destroys. How can I destroy my view completely?

For example:

```
struct Home: View {


    var body : some View { 
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination : SliderView()){
               Text("\(self.myData.lastText)").bold()
            } 
        }
    }

}


struct SliderView: View {


    @ObservedObject myData : MyData = MyData()

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body : some View { 
        VStack {
            Button(action : {
                 self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() 
            }) { 
                Text("Dismiss").bold() 
            }
            Text("\(self.myData.lastText)").bold()
        } 
    }

}
```

When I go to `SliderView` then go back and go to `SliderView` again, `self.myData.lastText` is not empty, and it has previous value.

Comment: You probably have a reference to it. Please post the minimal code to reproduce the issue

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini updated question, please read it again

Answer (score 2):

As of Xcode 12 & iOS 14, you can now use `@StateObject`. See the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced same symptoms.
the reason is that
`Home` is not recreated when go back to Home as Home is root view
and `Home`'s `NavigationLink` contains `SliderView()` and use existing `SliderView`

I think you can test the below and find `SliderView` is recreated and load data again.
This is just showing what make the problem. I don't think the code below is good.
as I have short experience on SwiftUI. kindly let me know if something wrong. and I don't know what is the best approach to solve this. though the below code can solve the problem.

```
struct Home: View {
    @State var appearCount = 0

    var body : some View { 
        VStack {
            if (appearCount > 0) {
                //this code is added just for re draw view. when appearCount is changed
            }
            NavigationLink(destination : SliderView()){
               Text("\(self.myData.lastText)").bold()
            } 
        }.onAppear { appearCount += 1 }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `view` **is** destroying, but the new `view` uses the previous `viewModel`.

You are referencing the same `MyData()` object all the time. So if you change it anywhere, all references will be updated. And since seems like you are observing for changes (`@ObservedObject`) in realtime, it will update as soon as it changes anywhere.

You should provide more detail for more accurate information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to destroying my viewModel also. How can I do that?

Comment: You should not destroy anything yourself. You just don't keep a reference to it and ARC will handle destroying it if needed.

Comment: Seems like you need a `@State` instead

Comment: I do not have any references to it. I create `myData` inside `SliderView` and also use it there

Comment: You changed the original question. hmm. As I mentioned before, there is a lack of information about your code. if you just need `myModel` inside the `SlideView`, so why you need a `@ObservedObject` at first place? you should consider using a `@State` instead.

Comment: I `@ObservedObject` because MyData is a class not a struct, so changes in it does not affect the view

Comment: You don't do anything with that in the example you provided. So you don't need it. Just pass **the value** there, NOT entire data model!